# Word for someone who complains about others not following the rules despite it not being such a big deal

Tags: adjectives

I need a word for a person who tells people to follow the rules even though it's not such a big deal. Is there evem a word for it?
The guy pretty much spoiled the fun just because he wants people to follow the rules while he's breaking them sometimes himself..

OR. A word to describe a person who tells people every time " don't do that, it's not allowed" literally every time over every LITTLE thing that happens.

Comment: An *English teacher*!

Comment: You've provided two quite different descriptions, which is likely to lead to two different kinds of answer. Please [edit] your question to focus on one meaning only, as it's currently too broad. For further guidance, see [ask] and take the **[Tour]**. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Stickler is the word you are looking for. It means a person who insists on a certain quality or type of behaviour. Disciplinarian could also be used.